# Вывод имени клиента в input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть две страницы.

1. Клиенты
2. Заказы

Сначала добавляться информация клиента в mysql, через первую страницу. 
Нужно, чтобы при добавлении заказа со второй страницы, можно было выбрать имя клиента, который уже есть в БД.
**Вопрос:** Как сделать, чтобы при вводе первых букв имени клиента в поле выпадало нужное имя и его можно было бы выбрать.

Comment: мин. код бы. при каждом отпускании клавишы слать запрос на бд со значением в инпут. Там проверять совпадение строки с масивом пользователей если совпадает возвращать - делать штмл элемент с его именем и добавлять

Comment: @Horchynskyi, вам не кажется это немножко ущербным?

Comment: @Cactus, в плане?

Comment: @Horchynskyi,  ну дак, например я буду вводить имя, введу неверно, к тому же могу просто вводить максимальное кол-во символов, я могу только представить какая нагрузка будет, если при каждом вводе символа делать запрос в бд, еще и проверки..Тут другой вариант должен быть какой-то.. Может вместо ручного ввода использовать `select + options`?

Comment: @Cactus, ну тогда уж сделать минимум на 3 буквы и только тогда делать запрос. Либо при добавлении польователя в бд делать с бд запрос на страницу и там получать масив и уже по нему сортировать с инпута

Comment: ну либо попробовать Jquery UI Autocomplete. Будет всего один запрос к бд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошо бы, конечно знать, каким конкретно образом должны "выбираться" данные.

Создайте инпут, там вводите данные, как выше в комментарии написали на событии отпускания клавиши производите ajax запрос. В файле php найдите совпадения с полями базе и составте ответ. Массив, в каждую ячейку вложи id и имя. И при выборе имени в выпадающем окне на onclick добавляй эти данные куда будет нужно.

```
<input type="search" id="ajax_search">

<script>
$("#ajax_search").on('keyup', function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'место, где получать результат будешь',
    data: {value:value}
    success: function(e){
      'здесь обрабатываешь результат. Имя, id, или другие данные.'
    }
  })
}
</script>
```